# I can't able to perform the modulo division in this switch statement program

Tags: c, switch-statement, operators, operator-keyword, modulo

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    char operators;
    double a,b;

    printf("Enter a operator from the following(+,-,*,/,%): ");
    scanf("%c",&operators);
    printf("Enter the two values: ");
    scanf("%lf,%lf", &a,&b);
    switch (operators)
    {
        case '+':
            printf("%lf+%lf=%lf",a,b,a+b);
            break;
        case'-' :
            printf("%lf_%lf=%lf",a,b,a-b);
            break;
        case '*':
            printf("%lf*%lf=%lf",a,b,a*b);
            break;
        case '/':
            printf("%lf/%lf=%lf",a,b,a/b);
            break;
/*modulo division*/
        case '%':
            printf("%lf%%lf=%lf",a,b,a%b);
            break;
        default:
            printf("you have entered a wrong operator.please check and come again");

    }
```

I need to perform the modulo division in the switch statement.

Comment: What is the problem, what errors do you get?

Comment: line 28; [Error] invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double' to binary 'operator%'

Answer (score 0):

To compute the remainder of `double` values, you can use `fmod`:

```
printf("%lf%%lf=%lf", a, b, fmod(a, b));
```

`fmod` is declared in the header `<math.h>`, so your program should include that before using `fmod` (and outside of any function):

```
#include <math.h>
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes You will have to convert a and b to int from float. Float values cannot be used in modulo dividion (if you think about this , it should be very intuitive).
Convert them to int by something like this :

```
int z = a;
int x = b;
```

Then use z and x where you have used a and b to do modulo division.

Comment: have you heard of `fmod`?

Comment: @kiranBiradar `fmod` sure as heck ain't an operator , is it ? It also requires an extra `#include <math.h>` which makes it closer to `pow()` than `%` .